# React query useQueries Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have the following hook to fetch multiple queries:

```
function useClientSurveys(surveysIds) {
  const { isAdmin } = useAdminStatus();
  return useQueries(
    surveysIds &&
      surveysIds.map(surveyId => ({
        queryKey: ['clientSurvey', surveyId],
        queryFn: () => getSurvey(surveyId),
        enabled: !isAdmin && !!surveysIds,
      }))
  );
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
  const dummyIds = [
    '1234534324326',
    '3487236482376'
  ]

  const {
    data: clientSurveys,
    isError: isClientSurveysError,
    isLoading: isClientSurveysLoading,
  } = useClientSurveys(dummyIds);
```

I keep getting undefined even though I know the array is defined because it's hard-coded in this case.

What may be causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the documentation, you need to pass your queries as an object.

```js
useQueries({
  queries: surveysIds.map(surveyId => ({
    queryKey: ['clientSurvey', surveyId],
    queryFn: () => getSurvey(surveyId),
    enabled: !isAdmin && !!surveysIds,
  }))
})
```

[UseQueries documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQueries)

Comment: you also need to make sure that `surveysIds` is an array. OP had a check with `surveysIds && surveysIds.map(...)` and that won't work. It needs to be something like: `surveyIds?.map(...) ?? []`

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem with

```
  return useQueries(
      surveysIds.map(surveyId => ({
        queryKey: ['clientSurvey', surveyId],
        queryFn: () => getSurvey(surveyId),
        enabled: !isAdmin && !!surveysIds,
      })) ?? []
  );
```